# How do I diagnose laptop freezing with no logs?

Tags: 20.04, freeze, diagnostic

Running Ubuntu 22.04.3 on Intel system.  HP Pavilion DV4-3029TX PC i5-2410 Intel HD Graphics 3000 (with 8GB mem)

Tried both default kernel 5.15 & HWE kernel 6.2, 6.5

System will just randomly freeze several times per day.  Sometimes when idle but sometimes in mid use.  Complete freeze means no key board or mouse and last thing scene on screen just remains there and wont respond to a remote ping.

After power cycling to reboot and check the log but the few minutes around the freeze time are always missing.

I don't see any critical errors in the log during the subsequent boot so I'm unsure what my next step is for diagnosing.

There are so many of these posts in here that I've spent hours chasing red herrings.

Any pointers appreciated.

Updated:

Freezes can happen at any time with or without applications running.  So shouldn't be lack of memory.

Memtest86+ 5.31b passed without error.

Tested :

```
Ubuntu 22.04.3 desktop installation (Wayland) : freezes
Ubuntu 22.04.3 desktop live CD (Xorg) : freezes
Ubuntu MATE 22.04.3 desktop live CD (Xorg) : partially stable
Armbian 23.11 (AMD) Bookworm Xfce : OK - Stable
Windows 10 : OK - Stable
```

Both MATE and Ubuntu have SNAPS so it shouldn't be that.

Update:

I enabled watchdog with verbose output and file system sync with an interval of every 10 seconds.

Some output from syslog at time of freeze:

```
Jan 18 17:44:23 DV4 watchdog[9709]: got answer on ping=1 from target 127.0.0.1       time=0.009ms
Jan 18 17:44:33 DV4 watchdog[9709]: still alive after 7891 interval(s)
Jan 18 17:44:33 DV4 watchdog[9709]: got answer on ping=1 from target 127.0.0.1       time=0.009ms
Jan 18 17:44:43 DV4 watchdog[9709]: still alive after 7892 interval(s)
Jan 18 18:53:54 DV4 systemd-modules-load[325]: Inserted module 'lp'
Jan 18 18:53:54 DV4 systemd-modules-load[325]: Inserted module 'ppdev'
Jan 18 18:53:54 DV4 systemd-modules-load[325]: Inserted module 'parport_pc'
Jan 18 18:53:54 DV4 systemd-modules-load[325]: Inserted module 'msr'
```

The kernel log at around the same time shows:

```
Jan 18 17:14:47 DV4 kernel: [161070.600944] wlp10s0: associated
Jan 18 17:14:47 DV4 kernel: [161070.682404] wlp10s0: Limiting TX power to 27 (27 - 0) dBm as advertised by 3c:7c:3f:6b:ea:28
Jan 18 18:53:54 DV4 kernel: [    0.000000] microcode: updated early: 0x15 -> 0x2f, date = 2019-02-17
Jan 18 18:53:54 DV4 kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 6.5.0-14-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-110) (x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38) #14~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Nov 20 18:15:30 UTC 2 (Ubuntu 6.5.0-14.14~22.04.1-generic 6.5.3)
Jan 18 18:53:54 DV4 kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-14-generic root=UUID=424f70c0-d496-4afc-ae1d-9c7b44b2d383 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
```

The crash is around 17:44:33-43. The reboot is at 18:53:54.

So nothing identified.  Whatever is causing the freeze is too quick or severe to write anything to the logs!

But the system was powered off implying watchdog shutdown the system.  Because normally the system is always remais powered on when it freezes.

Comment: Is this a useful starting point? https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/kernel-crash-dump

Comment: By no keyboard, do you mean you can't directly command the kernel (via SysRq commands; which will bypass any stuck/unresponsive gui/UI).  You've tagged 20.04, but mention 22.04 so which is it?  You also mention intel graphics, so is this a server or desktop as you don't specify.

Comment: If nothing is logged, then include hardware causes among the possibilities: Loose internal connections, cracked motherboard, some RAM gone bad, dying power supply, etc.

Comment: As with any troubleshooting, try to reduce the number of variables. Change jut one variable at a time. See if you can spot patterns that help with reproducing the freeze. Example: Try to reproduce the freeze with a LiveUSB's "Try Ubuntu" environment on the affected hardware, and also using the same LiveUSB on different hardware.

Comment: Alternat debug method: guess a problem and test for it.  Is it bad hardware? (run hardware diagnostics, starting with memtest and then cpuburn or stress)  Is it running out of memory? (try adding swap and watch for growth)

Comment: Not enough info. HP support lists 6 models starting DV4. First run memtest86 from the boot menu; leave it overnight. If if passes, try updating your BIOS.

Comment: System "freezes" are often caused by running too many, too large programs and running out of available memory. Use `free` to see if you have swap space, read `man mkswap swapon fstab fallocate` to create some. Swap space must be contiguous. use `mkswap` or `fallocate`, not `dd`. Traditionally, swap space of 1.5 × RAM has been recommended,  but YMMV. If you don't plan to hibernate your system, you can have less than 1.0 × RAM.

Comment: You still haven't clarified if you've tried directly commanding the kernel (ie. SysRq commands), as they will bypass any crashed GUI/UI (*you also didn't clarify if desktop or server install*).  This is I consider important detail; as if you don't get a response from SysRq commands, it usually indicates you have a kernel issue, thus reboot is essential & you need to explore systemd journals.

Comment: @guiverc Can confirm the key combo (Alt+PrtSc+REISUB) reboots the system when it is not frozen and doesn't do a thing when it is frozen.

Comment: That highlights a kernel issue...   where I'd start exploring your hardware. When was the last time you did a *cap-scan*, cleaned out the case etc??

Comment: It's a laptop.  Looked inside a few days ago while troubleshooting this issue.  Nice and clean inside.  Memory test also passed.

Comment: *clean* or *dirty*; a *swollen* cap will still cause a system to just *stop* and matches what you describe... Did you look (do a *cap scan*) whilst looking inside the motherboard..   Your alternative is to boot a *live* system (*ideally something different stack wise to what you have installed*) & use it as you do now; if its a hardware issue you'll have the system *stop* there too, highlighting a hardware issue & need to open up device & look again, grab a multimeter & check PSU etc. too  If it's not hardware related; you should have noted clues in system journals suggested earlier.

Comment: I don't think it's a cap because Windows 10 is rock solid on the same laptop.  I have just been running kstars (Windows) all day and no hangs.  I'm lucky to get 30 minutes with kstars under Linux.

Comment: Just finished testing from a live Ubuntu MATE flash drive.  Seems rock solid.  Next test Ubuntu 22.04.3 Desktop from live flash drive.

Comment: Just tested Ubuntu 22.04.3 Desktop live CD.  This one freezes.  So something unique to Ubuntu.  I did notice the live CD is Xwindows based but my installation is Wayland based and both freeze.

Comment: I will now retest MATE for longer to make sure.

Comment: Ubuntu-MATE is a Ubuntu system that only differs in that's its built by the same builders using a different seed file ([MATE](https://ubuntu-archive-team.ubuntu.com/seeds/ubuntu-mate.mantic/desktop) versus [Ubuntu Desktop](https://ubuntu-archive-team.ubuntu.com/seeds/ubuntu.mantic/desktop)...  At .3 they both use HWE, though if 22.04(.1) (no .2/.3/.4) the MATE ISO uses GA kernel stack (5.15) like Server where Ubuntu Desktop defaults to HWE (5.19 for .2, 6.2 for .3, 6.5 for .4). The *seed* file controls the packages included on ISO & thus installed (*what makes them different Ubuntu products*)

Comment: FYI:  For a rather different stack I'd opt for Debain, OpenSuSE, Fedora etc.. where defaults vary; a different Ubuntu just varies the package versions (kernel included for some ISOs only but not all, packages included & mainly just package versions). By different stack I was intending something very different; you mention Ubuntu-MATE which is the *identical* stack unless very different release was used; but gave no mention as to what ISO & thus stack was included (22.04.3 Ubuntu MATE & Ubuntu Desktop are almost identical stacks!)

Comment: @guiverc MATE also differs from regular Ubuntu in that it doesn't use Wayland at the moment.  I was just trying to isolate the windowing system.

Comment: @guiverc My retest of MATE also failed after several hours. But that is longer than my Ubuntu build which can fail after a few minutes.  I will now test Debian.

Comment: Armbian (AMD) Debian Bookworm Xfce desktop is rock solid.  I have to conclude that a regression has crept in Ubuntu's implementation.